# Can I use SQL's IN(...) statement for a namedQuery?

Tags: java, sql, named-query

How can I use IN at my namedQuery?

```
@NamedQueries(  
 {   
 @NamedQuery(name = "GetAvailableProducts", query = new StringBuilder("").append("SELECT   p   FROM Product p WHERE p.type= :type AND (p.available IN ('I want to define changeable size of an array or sometinhg like that') OR p.available = :available)")),  
 }
```

I mean that I can set 'type' parameter (I defined it as a variable----> :type) and I want to define variables inside of IN statement to. However the number of parameters are not constant. I want to define an array or something like that :array[] and I want to set it when I call that namedQuery.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### NamedQuery

```
@NamedQueries(  
{   
 @NamedQuery(name = "GetAvailableProducts", query = "FROM Product p WHERE p.type= :type AND (p.available IN (:availableCollection) OR p.available = :available)",  
}
```

### Set parameters

*Hibernate*:

```
query.setParameterList('availableCollection', yourCollection);
```

*JPA*:

```
query.setParameter('availableCollection', yourCollection);
```

Comment: My query variable is a "Query" type variable. It has setParameter() method but I couldn't see setParameterList() method?  Link: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html

Comment: import javax.persistence.Query; //I use this import for my query variable.

Comment: I used Hibernate API. JPA query indeed does not have `setParameterList` method. According to http://www.roseindia.net/jpa/eclipsejpaexamples/named-parameter-list.shtml you just use `setParameter` and pass a collection.

Comment: I can confirm that using JPA, query.setParameter does work for a list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

```
SELECT   p   FROM Product p WHERE p.type= :type AND (p.available IN 
('foo', 'bar') OR p.available = :available)
```

(if "available" is a string)

or

```
SELECT   p   FROM Product p WHERE p.type= :type AND (p.available IN 
(1, 2, 3) OR p.available = :available)
```

(if available is a number)?

Comment: In my program, number of variables will be changeable it maybe (1, 2) or (1, 2, 3) it depends. So I should define array like variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

Expression 'IN' in JPQL is equal to writing multiple 'OR' statements, in your case an example of 'IN' would be:

```
... p.available IN ('US', 'GB') ...
```

Which I believe is equal to:

```
... p.available = 'US' OR p.available = 'GB' ...
```

Here's a link that explains it well: [OpenJPA: IN Expression](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_in)

**EDIT**
P.S. Assuming p.available is String (character type)

**EDIT2**
The author has edited question so many times that I can't follow up him :) As for the actual question about passing array for IN-expression, here's a link of similar question on StackOverflow: [JPQL IN clause - Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets)

Comment: I'm sorry :) but I wanted to make more clear for everybody according to comments so I edittes it to make my question clear :)