# Enumeration List with IN operator in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql

Which is missing the following `JPQL query`?

```
SELECT h FROM WorkFlowHistory h WHERE h.referenceNo = :referenceNo 
AND h.workflowTask IN ('CONFIRMATION','PAYMENT','ISSUING')
```

Error :

```
invalid IN expression argument [CONFIRMATION]
```

Dynamic Query Method

```
public List<WorkFlowHistory> findWorkFlowHistoryByRefNo(String refNo, WorkflowTask ...workflowTasks) {
    ...
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("SELECT h FROM WorkFlowHistory h WHERE h.referenceNo = :referenceNo");
    if(workflowTasks != null && workflowTasks.length > 0) {
        buffer.append(" AND h.workflowTask IN (");
        for (int i = 0; i < workflowTasks.length; i++) {
            buffer.append("'" + workflowTasks[i] + "'");
            if ((i + 1) != workflowTasks.length) {
                buffer.append(",");
            }
        }
        buffer.append(")");
    }
    Query q = em.createQuery(buffer.toString());
    ....
}
```

My enum class

```
public enum WorkflowTask {
    UNDERWRITING("Underwriting"),
    SURVEY("Survey"),
    APPROVAL("Approval"),
    INFORM("Inform"),
    CONFIRMATION("Confirmation"),
    PAYMENT("Payment"),
    PROPOSAL_REJECT("Proposal Reject"),
    ISSUING("Issuing");

    private String label;

    private WorkflowTask(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that problem lies in representation of your Enums in DB. How are your enums mapped in the database `Ordinal` or `String`?

The best would be just putting your enums as parameter placeholder in your JPQL query:

```
SELECT h FROM WorkFlowHistory h WHERE h.referenceNo = :referenceNo 
AND h.workflowTask IN :workflowTasks
```

and than adding it as parameter to your query, something like this:

```
...
List<WorkflowTask> workflowTasks=Arrays.asList({WorkflowTask.CONFIRMATION, WorkflowTask.PAYMENT WorkflowTask.ISSUING });
...
Query q = em.createQuery(buffer.toString());
q.addParameter("workflowTasks", workflowTasks);
```

This way you don't have to think about how are your Enums represented in DB.

Comment: Thz, I also get it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets thank for your support