# JPA @namedQuery with "IN" expression

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query

Im having the following namedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Department.getDepartmentsByIds, query = "SELECT tbl FROM Department tbl where tbl.id in (:departmentsIds)")
```

I would like to pass the parameter: departmentsIds = "1,2,3" like this:

```
query.setParameter("departmentsIds","1,2,3");
```

but i get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1,2,3] was not matching type [java.lang.Long]
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass a `List` to the `setParameter` method instead of a `String`.  The generic type argument of `List` should correspond with the type of your `departmentIds` field.

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //this should be your id column's type
ids.add(1);
ids.add(2);
ids.add(3);
query.setParameter("departmentsIds",ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

The column `id` in `Department` is of type `java.lang.Long` and in your `setParameter` you are  trying to set `String` `[1,2,3]` thats why you see `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, the correct way to implements is as @Kevin suggested create a `List` of `Long` type and add your arguments.