# SqlServer PrepareStatement set parameters for SQL 'in(?)' clause

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have a `sql` which looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T_TABLE WHERE ID IN(?)
```

I wanna to set parameters for `IN(?)` via `PrepareStatement`. I think the desired method would looked like this:

```
prepareStatement.setList(1,Arrays.asList("1","2","3"));
```

But I don't know which method should I use to achieve this.

I have tried `setArray` method with the help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842211/how-to-use-an-arraylist-as-a-prepared-statement-parameter) and I got these error messages.

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException:
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createArrayOf(SQLServerConnection.java:2763)
    at com.newegg.ec.review.summary.dao.mssql.MSSQLReviewAccess.nextPage(MSSQLReviewAccess.java:165)
```

Does it mean that SqlService is not support `createArrayOf` method? And now, how can I achieve this? I don't like the way to join `sql` like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_TABLE WHERE ID IN("+in+")";
```

My code,

```
ps.setArray(1, conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR",items.subList(1,9);
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you are wanting to do is not **directly**possible using a PreparedStatement.

Have a look at this wonderful article which shows other alternatives
http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Alternatively you can use a createQuery statement which will accept an IN clause as per
[JPQL IN clause: Java-Arrays (or Lists, Sets...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets)

Comment: Thanks for your post. Greate article that let me know more about PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

See [`PreparedStatement.setInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29), which takes the parameter index and value:

```
private String sqlParams(int numParams) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(numParams <= 0) return sb.toString();
    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < numParams - 1; ++ctr) {
        sb.append("?,");
    }
    sb.append("?");
    return sb.toString();
}

/** In the method that accesses the DB... */
/** paramArray is an array of parameters for the IN clause. */
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = sqlObj.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM T_TABLE WHERE ID IN(" + sqlParams(paramArray.length) + ")");
for(int idx = 0; idx < paramArray.length; ++idx) {
    preparedStatement.setInt(idx, paramArray[idx]);
}
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not what I want. In my case, the `sql` statement is in a file. I want to read it from file and set parameters for it, not modify it.