# Count using native SQL in JPA Data Spring returns 0

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with one query/interface:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(1) FROM que_table que " +
            "WHERE que.CREATED_DATE >= (SELECT CREATED_DATE " +
            "   FROM que_table " +
            "   WHERE id = :selectedId " +
            "   ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC LIMIT 1) " +
            "AND que.QUEUE_STATUS in (:queueStatuses)", nativeQuery = true)
    Long countCurrentPosition(@Param("selectedId ") String selectedId , @Param("queueStatuses") Set<QueueStatus> queueStatuses);
```

I connect to MySQL using spring-data-JPA.
When I run this query on console it's working perfectly.

What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the SQL generated?

Comment: Try removing the parens around `:queueStatuses`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677310/spring-data-jpa-repositories-in-clause-in-derived-query-not-working

Comment: I have tried without brackets. The result is the same. The query looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

use string name of QueueStatus enum :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(1) FROM que_table que " +
            "WHERE que.CREATED_DATE >= (SELECT CREATED_DATE " +
            "   FROM que_table " +
            "   WHERE id = :selectedId " +
            "   ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC LIMIT 1) " +
            "AND que.QUEUE_STATUS in (:queueStatuses)", nativeQuery = true)
    Long countCurrentPosition(@Param("selectedenter code hereId ") String selectedId , @Param("queueStatuses") Set<String> queueStatuses);
```