# How to correct create JPQL request?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have repository method:

```
@Query(value = "select t from Transaction t " +
        "where t.bankAccountId in (:bankAccountIds) " +
        "and t.tradeTime is not null " +
        "and t.ccy is not null " +
        "and t.net is not null " +
        "and t.tradeTime >= :startDate and t.tradeTime <= :endDate " +
        "and t.status = :status")
List<Transaction> findAllByBankAccountIdInAndTradeTimeBetween(@Param("bankAccountIds") Iterable<UUID> bankAccountIds,
                                                              @Param("status") TransactionStatus status,
                                                              @Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate,
                                                              @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate);
```

But when I tried to use this code I have exception:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at
> or near ")"

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPQL IN clause: Java-Arrays (or Lists, Sets...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets)

Comment: no, it's not my question =(

Comment: You need to pass in a `List`, and use the correct syntax is `IN :bankAccountIds`.

Comment: You may an empty argument List so you end up with `...IN ()....`

Comment: Add full stacktrace of the exception after removing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the brackets (:bankAccountIds)

Comment: i have another methods where there is brackerts and it works

Comment: Is it receiving a single value or a list?

Comment: receiving a list

Comment: Have you tried to use a List instead of the Iterable?