# Is it possible in Hibernate to replace multiple calls with different parameters in a loop with one call?

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a `@NamedQuery` which counts number of `Person` with given name:

```java
 @NamedQuery(name = "Person.countNames", query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Person p WHERE p.name= :name")
```

I'm using this query in a loop to count `Person` for a specific list with names:

```java
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Stan", "Robert");
HashMap<String, Long> results = new HashMap<>();
for (String name : names){
   Long count = entityManager.createNamedQuery('Person.countNames').setParameter("name", name)
   results.put(name, count);
}
```

I would like to optimize this process to only call once to the database. Is it possible to create such `@NamedQuery` which will give immediate results in `HashMap` or in any other form?

Comment: You can use Lists with the EntityManager object as a parameter. I mean, `WHERE p.name = :name` can be replaced with `WHERE p.name IN :names`. Then, add a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: That would be a really nice solution, but e.g. in my case, if there is zero Stan's in a database, it would return only 2 results but there should be 3 with one row with zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```java
public Map<String, Integer> getCountForNames(String... names) {
    List<String> namesAsList = Arrays.asList(names);

    String hql = "SELECT p.name, count(*) FROM Person p WHERE p.name IN (:names) GROUP BY p.name";
    TypedQuery<Object[]> q = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Object[].class);
    q.setParameter("names", namesAsList);

    List<Object[]> result = q.getResultList();
    final Map<String, Integer> toReturn = new HashMap<>();

    result.forEach(res -> {
        String name = (String) res[0];
        Integer count = (Integer) res[1];
        toReturn.put(name, count);
    });
  return Collections.unmodifiableMap(toReturn);
}
```

More info can be found here: [JPQL IN clause: Java-Arrays (or Lists, Sets...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets).

Also denote that, if you want to use a Named Query, you can change:

```java
String hql = "SELECT p.name, count(*) FROM Person p WHERE p.name IN (:names) GROUP BY p.name";
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Object[].class);
```

with:

```java
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Person.countNames", Object[].class);
```

Comment: That's a better solution than my current one, but I would like to avoid casting or creating a new class (with only name and count) for this entity. Is there a solution to retrieve only count numbers without names?

Comment: You can either retrieve an array of objects or a specific object. You can do `.createQuery(hql,Integer.class);` and return `List<Integer>`, but you won't be able to know which number represents which name. You can also directly return a `List<Object[]>` instead of a `Map<String,Integer>`, being `Object[0]` the name and `Object[1]` the count of that name, but you will be casting it in another place, so... as you prefer. If you want to know which name is associated with each Integer, having in mind you will need to cast it, I would go with the approach of the answer. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Also, please, consider marking the answer as accepted if it was helpful and it resolved your question. Thanks in advance.